# Show decimal expansions

Tags: decimal-expansion, geometric-series

I can't wrap my head around this exercise:

Show that the rational number $\frac 94$ has two different decimal expansions, namely $2.2500000\dots$ and $2.2499999\dots$ by writing these decimal expansions in the form

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\times 10^{-i}$$

for certain numbers $$a_i$$ and then using the formula for the sum of the geometric series.

I started by defining $$a_{ix} = 0.a_{i0}a_{i1}...$$ where $$a_i = \{2,5,0\}$$ with $$a_{i4} < a_{i0} = a_{i1} < a_{i3} = a_{in}$$ for the first case, and where $$a_i = \{ 2,4,9 \}$$ with $$a_{i0} = a_{i1} < a_{i2} < a_{i3} = a_{in}$$ for the second case.

Then defining

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\times 10^{-i}$$

as

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i\times 10^{-i} = \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{9 \times a_i}{1 - 10^{n + 1}}$$

any hints if this is on the right track?

Comment: As a general suggestion, first show the basic $1=.\overline 9$  And use that to show the specific things you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By formula for the sum of the geometric series ${a \over 1 - r}$:

\begin{align*}
2.2499999\ldots &= 2 + \frac{2}{10^1} + \frac{4}{10^2} + \frac{9}{10^3} + \frac{9}{10^4} + \ldots \\
&= 2 + \frac{2}{10^1} + \frac{4}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^3} \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} 9 \cdot 10^{-k} \\
&= 2 + \frac{2}{10^1} + \frac{4}{10^2} + \frac{1}{10^3} \cdot \frac{9}{1 - \frac{1}{10}} \\
&= 2.24 + \frac{1}{10^2} \cdot 1 \\
&= 2.25
\end{align*}